# C# dictionary keeps erasing values after every iteration

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

So I have a problem... I am trying to consolidate 5 or so bilingual dictionaries, in HTML format, into a single, multilingual dictionary, with english as the source language. To do this, I decided to set up a dictionary, and map each non-english word to it's english counterpart(key) [see code below].

```
1 public void ConsolidateDictionary(string directoryPath)
2 {
3    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
4    string key = string.Empty;
5    string value = string.Empty;
6    Dictionary<string, List<string>> languages = 
         new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
7    List<string> temp = new List<string>();
8    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.EnumerateFiles())
9    {
10       HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
11       doc.Load(file.FullName);
12
13       foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//wordunit"))
14       {
15          foreach (HtmlNode child in node.SelectNodes(".//word"))
16           {
17                   if (child.Attributes["language"].Value == "EN")
18                   {
19                       key = child.OuterHtml.ToString();
20                   }
21                   else
22                   {
23                       value = child.OuterHtml.ToString();
24                   }
25           }
26
27           if (key != null && value != null)
28           {
29               if (languages.ContainsKey(key))
30               {
31                   foreach (var item in languages[key])
32                   {
33                       temp.Add(item);
34                   }
35                   temp.Add(value);
36                   languages.Remove(key);
37                   languages.Add(key, temp);
38                   temp.Clear();
39               }
40               else
41               {
42                       temp.Add(value);
43                       languages.Add(key, temp);
44                       temp.Clear();
45               }
46           }
47       }
48   }
49   WriteFile(languages);
50 }
```

basically what is happening is, after each iteration of the foreach loop at line 15, the existing dictionary values are all nulled (but the keys remain). So, say that after the first iteration of the loop at line 15, the dictionary (called 'languages') contained: `key: <word language="EN">Hello</word>  Value: <word language="ES">Hola</word>`; when the second iteration comes around, the value is removed from the dictionary 'languages', leaving only:

```
key: <word language="EN">Hello</word>
Value: null
key: <word language="EN">Goodbye</word>
Value: <word language="ES">Chao</word>
```

(where the Goodbye-Chao pair were passed in as the key-value pair for the second iteration).

What could be causing this strange behavior... to my knowledge I'm not overwriting the values in my dictionary at all! Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: After David and Jeremy's answer, I think it would be worthwhile to note that, in C#, a Dictionary does not create a working copy of a variable... in fact, it merely references said variable, so any changes made to the variable are reflected in the Dictionary. I know it seems intuitive(especially after the fact), but, well, I didn't catch it, and there might be someone else who could get hung up on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp.Add(value);
 //languages.Add(key, temp);
temp.Clear();
```

Look at what you're doing to that poor List instance.  Use a new List instance for each key.

---

```
if (!languages.ContainsKey(key))
{
  languages.Add(key, new List<string>())
}
languages[key].Add(value);
```

Comment: That's correct, but it doesn't answer the question of why the logic is flawed.

Comment: There's only one list instance.  That list instance has Clear called against it.  What more is there to explain?

Comment: See my answer- the loop over word nodes needs to be expanded to include the (admittedly poorly written) check for existence in the dictionary.

Comment: Correction to myself- the logic is flawed in both ways.  Both of our fixes need to be applied to make it work properly.

Comment: This directly answers why the lists are empty, which is why you copied it to your answer.  Happy to help.

Comment: You are right on here- I mistook what input the OP was dealing with because of the extra loop in there.  Your answer is correct.

Comment: Now here is what I am wondering: the fact that the dictionary references the list instead of creating a working copy of it in it's own stack space: Is this a property of the List() or of the Dictionary()? I.E. I *believe* that a List() is mutable in C#, and so is a dictionary. Does the fact that the dictionary references the list instead of replicating reflect the properties of mutable objects in C#, or is it a memory management feature built into the Dictionary method?

Comment: Instances of reference types live on the heap and can (surprise) reference each other.  There is nothing special that Dictionary or List are doing other than being reference types.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting temp the value to every key. You want to create a new object for temp each time you are assigning it. Once you call clear, you are wiping it on every item.

You are using the same list the entire time. So you add items to the first key, then clear it. This will clear everything you put into that value.

Fixed:

```
public void ConsolidateDictionary(string directoryPath)
{
   DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
   string key = string.Empty;
   string value = string.Empty;
   Dictionary<string, List<string>> languages = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
   List<string> temp = null;
   foreach (FileInfo file in directory.EnumerateFiles())
   {
       HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
       doc.Load(file.FullName);

       foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//wordunit"))
       {
          foreach (HtmlNode child in node.SelectNodes(".//word"))
           {
                   if (child.Attributes["language"].Value == "EN")
                   {
                       key = child.OuterHtml.ToString();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       value = child.OuterHtml.ToString();
                   }
           }

           if (key != null && value != null)
           {
               if (languages.ContainsKey(key))
               {
                if(languages[key].Items.Contains(value) == false)
                         languages[key].Add(value);
               }
               else
               {
                    languages.Add(key, new List<string>);
                    languages[key].Add(value);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   WriteFile(languages);
 }
```